# How to stop Windows Security popup for Sharepoint 2007 site with anonymous access enabled

Tags: asp.net, security, iis, sharepoint, anonymous-access

I've been researching this a lot lately and cannot seem to find a solution to the exact problem I'm having, so I figured I'd ask and get any help I can get.

Here's the scenario: I took over a Sharepoint web application that was in development for a client.  I finished adding the rest of the content for him and he wanted to go live with the site once I finished.  I am wanting to make the entire web site (web application) public so I completed the steps to allow anonymous access for the entire web site.

The problem I'm encountering now is that every time someone goes to the site, it pops up with a window asking for the username and password.  When you cancel it, then the site pops up as it should and you can view anything on the site. However, each time you click to go to the Home page (default.aspx), it pops up with the Windows Security again.  Basically you can view the whole site as intended without logging in, but the popup happens each time going to the default.aspx page to where you have to keep cancelling to continue viewing the site. Of course this needs to stop since the site will be public for users and many do not have a log in. This obviously will confuse people trying to see the site because they'd think they need to log in.

Does anyone have some suggestions to why this is happening and how to stop it?  None of the other Sharepoint sites we've made have had this issue when enabling anonymous access so it's not an issue we've come across before.  I've looked at the other sites and how they're set up and it looks identical to this site that is having the popup issue. There's also not been a need before to adjust IE Internet Option settings since that was one solution I've seen.

Any help would be appreciated. I've tried researching and couldn't find a solution I needed and I'm at a loss.  I can provide any additional info if needed. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This can happen (and most probably) if a resource is not published in your site. Make sure to publish all your resources (Images, CSS & JS files.. etc) and then give it a try.

Comment: Yeah that was it!  I just noticed after I asked.  One of the images on the front page was not published...therefore was causing the login prompt.  Didn't even notice it until earlier when the image was not showing when I wasn't logged on, but it did display when I was.  Once I published the site worked.  Talk about a duh moment lol.  Figured it would be something rather simple.  Appreciate the response :)